# R: using param_get

Tags: r

I am new to R, migrating from SAS :) I have the following df:

```
id      scd     cat     qs
700689  1       di      NS=Ev12&id=1048&id2=1048&id3=ZX&HId=xl
```

The qs is a url decoded query string and I am trying to get the following output

```
id      scd  cat    qs                               NS   id  id2  id3 HId
700689  1    di     NS=Ev12&id=1&id2=10&id3=Z&HId=x  Ev12  1   10  Z    X
```

I am using the following code and the output seems to add a"q." to every column. I am unable to use any function on the added columns.

raw2$q <- param_get(raw2$qs, c("NS","id","id2","id3",HId"))

e.g. test <- na.omit(raw2$NS) does not work.

Any suggestion and help will be appreciated

Comment: Why is the `qs` column different between the two `df`s? What is the rule for shortening the value after `=`?

Comment: Please include all non-base packages in your question (`urltools`?).

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error, the values should be identical.

Comment: I used library(urltools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails because `param_get` (assuming it is the function from [the package urltools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/index.html)) does not return a single value, and you are telling it to bind it to the column named `q`.

If all you want to do is bind the columns to the data frame, you could use `cbind` from base r

```
# To recreate your example
library(urltools)
id <- 700689
scd  <- 1     
cat <- 'di'
qs <- 'NS=Ev12&id=1048&id2=1048&id3=ZX&HId=xl'
raw <- data.frame(id, scd, cat, qs)

# The line you need
cbind(raw, param_get(raw$qs, c("NS","id","id2","id3","HId")))
```

Which returns

```
      id scd cat                                      qs   NS   id  id2 id3 HId
1 700689   1  di NS=Ev12&id=1048&id2=1048&id3=ZX&HId=xl  Ev12 1048 1048  ZX  xl
```

Comment: Please include all non-base packages in your answer (`urltools`?) (esp when not included in the question).

Comment: Ah right, thanks. It wasn't mentioned in the question, it is the only library that has `param_get` in r that I know of.

Comment: Thank You, I see why i was getting this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following with `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  extract(qs, str_extract_all(df$qs, "(?<=^|&).+?(?==|$)")[[1]], 
          "^.+?=(.+)&.+?=(.+)&.+?=(.+)&.+?=(.+)&.+?=(.+)$", remove = FALSE)
```

or:

```
str_extract_all(df$qs, "(?<==).+?(?=&|$)") %>%
  lapply(setNames, str_extract_all(df$qs, "(?<=^|&).+?(?==|$)")[[1]]) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>%
  cbind(df, .)
```

**Result:**

```
      id scd cat                                     qs   NS   id  id2 id3 HId
1 700689   1  di NS=Ev12&id=1048&id2=1048&id3=ZX&HId=xl Ev12 1048 1048  ZX  xl
```